# Clean way to initialize php arrays

Tags: php

I often need constructs like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $entry) {
    if(!isset($data[$entry->type])) {
        $data[$entry->type] = 0;
    }
    $data[$entry->type] += $entry->value;
}
```

I think this is incredibly ugly and not very easy to read. Any ideas how to solve this and make it more fluent / easy to read / faster to type?

I usually don't care too much about these kind of "problems" but I need these constructs quite a lot and am always a bit ashamed of myself after writing them.

Comment: what happen if `$entry->type` is not set?

Comment: I can usually expect that type is set. But that's not really the point of the question. You could certainly add more code to handle that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done beautifully in PHP 7.0+ with the null coalescing operator:

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $entry) {
    $data[$entry->type] = $entry->value + ($data[$entry->type] ?? 0);
}
```

`$data[$entry->type] ?? 0` returns the value of `$data[$entry->type]` or 0 if it doesn't exist. For more information see [the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

Answer (score 0):

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) would be more suitable in this case.

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $entry) {
    if(empty($data[$entry->type])) {
        $data[$entry->type] = 0;
    }else{
        $data[$entry->type] += $entry->value;
    }
}
```

You can also use ternary operator.

```
$data[$entry->type] = empty($data[$entry->type]) ? 0 : $data[$entry->type] + $entry->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Much cleaner solution is using ternary operator:

```
$data[$entry->type] = isset($data[$entry->type])?$data[$entry->type] + $entry->value:0;
```

Although I would guess that you don't mean 0 as a starting value, but `$entry->value` if it is first time this type is met:

```
$data[$entry->type] = isset($data[$entry->type])?$data[$entry->type] + $entry->value:$entry->value;
```

Comment: While the ternary operator is a bit faster to type (91 chars vs. 113 chars), I don't really think it's a lot easier to read and not really addressing the main issue I think I have with the code. I really don't like to repeat $data[$entry->type] 3 times to essentially do 1 operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can either a) check PHP coding standards http://www.php-fig.org/ if you are concerned more about style of the code b) use ternary operator for if/else statement if you are concerned more about efficiency.

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $entry)
{
    $data[$entry->type] = empty($data[$entry->type]) ? 0 : $data[$entry->type] + $entry->value;
}
```